# Which Table is Holding Layers Information and Relationship with Actual Tables in Enterprise Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase

Can you please let me know which table(s) of Enterprise Geodatabase on top of SQL Server contains contains information about layer ID showing on service URL

[image]

```
"layers": [
  {
   "id": 0,
   "name": "Electric.DBO.Open_Point"
  },
  {
   "id": 1,
   "name": "Electric.DBO.Fuse"
  },
  {
   "id": 2,
   "name": "Electric.DBO.Circuit_Breaker"
  },
  {
   "id": 3,
   "name": "Electric.DBO.Recloser"
  },
  {
   "id": 4,
   "name": "Electric.DBO.Switch"
  },
   ...
```

and how they are connected (has reationship) with physical tables in Geodatabase?

[image]

Comment: Is that not just the layer order (ex MXD)?  I'm trying to remember how it works

Comment: You seem to be crossing enterprise geodatabase metadata with ArcGIS Server service layers. There is no overlap in these two abstractions.

Comment: As Vince mentioned, there is no relationship between ArcGIS Server/REST  layer IDs and geodatabase layer IDs.  Verify this by querying the SDE_Layers table in SQL Server.  The geodatabase keeps its own set of IDs and other layer info for many other geodatabase purposes.